# How does the findRoute function in Eloquent Javascript work exactly?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, ecmascript-6

I am having trouble understanding what the findRoute function does in the Eloquent Javascript book. I hope there is someone who can walk me through it, by using an example graph. What does the findRoute function do on every single iteration? Does the work array grow every time?

```js
// Places and roads of Meadowfield

const roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
];


//function to convert the roads to a graph

function buildGraph(edges) {

  let graph = Object.create(null);

  function addEdge(from, to) {

    if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    } else {
      graph[from].push(to);
    }
  }

  for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }

  return graph;

}

// assign the data structure to roadGraph

const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);


// The function that searches the shortest route between two places in roadGraph, the one that i need help with...

function findRoute(graph, from, to) {
  let work = [{at: from, route: []}];
  for (let i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
    let {at, route} = work[i];
    for (let place of graph[at]) {
      if (place == to) return route.concat(place);
      if (!work.some(w => w.at == place)) {
        work.push({at: place, route: route.concat(place)});
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(findRoute(roadGraph, "Alice's House", "Town Hall"))
```

Comment: A standard [Dijkstra algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) implementation. You'll find many detailed explanations, animations and talk-throughs on the web.

Comment: @Bergi I looked through those but I still can't grasp what exactly is happening in steps in the code. Perhaps you could explain?

Comment: The items in `work` from `i` to end are the queue. Iterating the `work` array is like taking elements out of the queue at the begin. `!work.some(w => w.at == place)` checks whether the `place` (the target node of the current edge) had already been visited. What parts of the code are you not understanding exactly? What parts *do* you understand?

Comment: At the first iteration work is empty right? So how does the loop continue after i = 0? I don't understand how it gets filled in the first place?

Comment: It's filled with `[{at: from, route: []}]` in the beginning to enable the first iteration

Comment: And the second iteration? work[1]? What is {at} and {route}?

Comment: It is whatever adjacent nodes were found in the first iteration.